# Make Camera follow target only on Y Axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script (attached to Main Camera) below makes the camera follow a specific target smoothly. But it follows the target on the x and y axis. What changes do we have to make so the camera follows the target only on Y axis while keeping its original x axis forever?

```
public float interpVelocity;
public float minDistance;
public float followDistance;
public GameObject target;
public Vector3 offset;
Vector3 targetPos;

void Start () {
    targetPos = transform.position;
}

void LateUpdate () {

    if (target)
    {
        Vector3 posNoZ = transform.position;
        posNoZ.z = target.transform.position.z;

        Vector3 targetDirection = (target.transform.position - posNoZ);

        interpVelocity = targetDirection.magnitude * 5f;

        targetPos = transform.position + (targetDirection.normalized * interpVelocity * Time.deltaTime); 

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp( transform.position, targetPos + offset, 0.25f);
    }
}
```

Comment: For hell's sake ... just use `Translate`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it by assigning only Y axis instead of whole vector. You can try something like,

```
void LateUpdate () {

    if (target)
    {
        Vector3 posNoZ = transform.position;
        posNoZ.z = target.transform.position.z;

        Vector3 targetDirection = (target.transform.position - posNoZ);

        interpVelocity = targetDirection.magnitude * 5f;

        Vector3 factorTowardsTarget = (targetDirection.normalized * interpVelocity * Time.deltaTime);

        targetPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x,transform.position.y + factorTowardsTarget.y,transform.position.z); 

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp( transform.position, targetPos + offset, 0.25f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your final line of code with `transform.position.y =  targetPos + offset;` My C# for unity is a little rusty so tell me if that doesn't work.

Another possible alternative in order to keep vector3.lerp would be just to write `this.transform.position.x` where you're assigning the x value

Answer (score 0):

In your last line, instead of

```
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp( transform.position, targetPos + offset, 0.25f);
```

...Try this:

```
Vector3 targetVec = targetPos + offset;
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position,
                                  new Vector3(transform.position.x, targetVec.y, targetVec.z),
                                  0.25f);
```

Here, I'm changing our target for the Vector-lerp to have our intended y and z, but keep the original transform's x-coord.

I hope that helps!